# Calling setImageBitmap not always work for ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

In my application the user selects a bitmap and then i use the following code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options op= new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,op);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Unfortunately, sometimes `ImageView` does not display anything
What can i do?

Comment: can you post your ImageView xml?

Comment: Add scaleType,adjustviewbounds true  ,image view src .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes bitmap is too large. Thats why imageview turns blank! I think that here you can find what you need: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem for Android 8 and low. There is no difference use method `setImageBitmap` or `setImageUri` : `ImageView` will be blank sometimes. There is no any errors and you can get `Bitmap` from `ImageView`.

Solution.

Use width and height of `Bitmap` for `ImageView` no more then double screen size, better is to fit to the screen size.